# How to forward the requested URL from Kong API gateway to back-end API micro-services

Tags: nginx, kong

I'm looking for a way to forward the client requested URL to Kong API gateway to my API micro-services. For example if I have my `kongw.com` pointing to my Kong Gateway I want to forward the whole domain to my micro-service.

Another example:

The client is requesting `mysubdomain.kongw.com/orders/list`. I want my micro-service to know whole URL that is requested.

I found out that I can configure Nginx to get the URL using its server_name wildcards. but the wildcards returned nothing. I wanted to send the result to my micro-service by adding `X-Wholerequest` parameter to the request. but it didn't work.

what is the right way to configure Nginx to do this ?
is  there any other way to handle this situation in Kong ?

Comment: So, you’ve a Kong cluster running at kongw.com and now you want to transform mysubdomain.kongw.com/orders-service to kongw.com/orders-service.
You could point CNAME mysubdomain.kongw.com to kongw.com and then have a kong routing rule to route all requests with host to a service kongw.com/orders-service.

Kong will evaluate any incoming HTTP request, provided you have implemented wildcard subdomains for APIs' public_dns. Another way, use url-rewrite, this plugin simply throws away the url set in kong route and uses the url set in it's configuration to proxy to the upstream.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you describe, in which Kong captures the full URL of the request, then adds that URL as a request header as the request is proxied upstream, is supported by the Kong Enterprise Edition Request Transformer plugin https://getkong.org/plugins/ee-request-transformer/ - which is included with a paid subscription to Mashape Enterprise.

It might also be possible to do this with custom NGINX configuration, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do so.

Comment: Apparently there is a free version of this same plugin: https://getkong.org/plugins/request-transformer/

Answer (score 0):

So, you’ve a Kong cluster running at kongw.com and now you want to transform mysubdomain.kongw.com/orders-service to kongw.com/orders-service.

You could point CNAME mysubdomain.kongw.com to kongw.com and then have a kong routing rule to route all requests with host to a service kongw.com/orders-service.

Kong will evaluate any incoming HTTP request, provided you have implemented wildcard subdomains for APIs' public_dns.

Another way, use url-rewrite, this plugin simply throws away the url set in kong route and uses the url set in it's configuration to proxy to the upstream.